# Matrix problem: Finding $P$ and $Q$ in $A=PBQ$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the lineal application $f:R^3(x)\longrightarrow{R^3(x)}$, $(x,y)=(x+y,x-y,3y)$

How can I find two basis $B_1$ and $B_2$ so that the matrix of $f$ is $ 
   A=M(f,B_1,B_2)=Q
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 \\
   0 & 0 \\
   \end{array} } \right]
$?.

I have $M(f,C_1,C_2)=  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 1 \\
   1 & -1 \\
   0 & 3\\
   \end{array} } \right]$

$\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 \\
   0 & 0 \\
   \end{array} } \right]
$=P$\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 1 \\
   1 & -1 \\
   0 & 3\\
   \end{array} } \right]$Q

Where $P=M(can_2,B_2)$ and $Q=M(B_1,can_1)$

Comment: what is $Q$?${}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Just take $(1,0,0),(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$ in the codomain and $(1,1,0),(1,-1,3),(0,0,0)$ in the codomain.

Comment: How did you come to this conclusion?